# Extract information from Html using VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, extract

I'm working on extracting information from the html through vb. The html file looks like:

```
<div class='titlebar'><h1>Event Log started at 02/06/2015 13:07:30</h1></div>
<div class='Information'><h1>02/06/2015 13:09:30 | Log has opened</h1></div>
<div class='Interest'><h1>02/06/2015 13:13:03 | finished!</h1></div>
<div class='Interest'><h1>02/06/2015 13:17:12 | finished!</h1></div>
<div class='Interest'><h1>02/06/2015 13:21:35 | finished!</h1></div>
<div class='Interest'><h1>02/06/2015 13:24:58 | finished!</h1></div>
<div class='Warning'><h1>02/06/2015 17:04:33 | Failed to stop, retrying...</h1></div>
<div class='Warning'><h1>02/06/2015 17:04:56 | Error during mix
```

From this, I need to be able to extract information into different listbox's for class =interest, class=warning and class=information. So through my research I obtained the below code:

```
Private Function getHtml(ByVal Adress As String) As String
    Dim rt As String = ""
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim wResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    wRequest = WebRequest.Create(Adress)
    wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
    SR.Close()
    Return rt
End Function

Private Sub btn_lookup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_lookup.Click
    TextBox2.Text = getHtml(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

The above code will copy the whole source information into the textbox. Is it possible only copy the specific information. So for

```
 <div class='Interest'><h1>02/06/2015 13:24:58 | finished!</h1></div>
```

I need to copy 02/06/2015 13:24:58 | finished!

Is this possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a HTML parser like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
Dim html As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\html.txt")
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim interestDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Interest')]")
Dim warningDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Warning')]")
Dim informationDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Information')]")

Dim lines = From div In interestDivs Select div.InnerText
lines = lines.Concat(From div In warningDivs Select div.InnerText)
lines = lines.Concat(From div In informationDivs Select div.InnerText)
TextBox2.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

If you are more familiar with LINQ than [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) you can also use these queries:

```
Dim interests = From div In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                Where div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") = "Interest"
                Select div.InnerText
Dim warnings = From div In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
               Where div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") = "Warning"
               Select div.InnerText
Dim infos = From div In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            Where div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") = "Information"
            Select div.InnerText
TextBox2.Lines = interests.Concat(warnings).Concat(infos).ToArray()
```

Comment: Just to mention I'm only familiar with VB at begineer's level .                          I will be reading from Html, so if I changed html = "C:\Desktop\test.html" do I need to modify anything, because doing so gives me an error because Lines are Null.

Comment: @SatvirSingh: the first line of my code shows how to read a text file. Just replace `ReadAllText("C:\Temp\html.txt")` with `ReadAllText("C:\Desktop\test.html")`

Comment: I modified your code a bit and now I can collect the data into the specific richtextboxes. Thank you for all the help

Comment: @SatvirSingh: glad that you've got it working. If you have further questions ask. You can edit your question to provide your modifications if you want. But i think it's not needed for future readers.

Comment: I have another question. Sometimes the data is not available in the html so for example I want to verify if this lines.Concat(From div In warningDivs Select div.InnerText) is not Null. How would I write.

Comment: @SatvirSingh: if you use the first approach you could first check if `interestDivs` is `Nothing`. In the second approach you can use `If interests.Any()`